# When casting the double value 0.9 to a long how can get 1?

Tags: java, casting

When casting the `double` value `0.9` (or any 0. decimal) to a long how can get `1`?

At present it returns 0.

Thanks

Comment: You need to specify the rounding rules you want to use.  What if the value is exactly 0.5?

Comment: @Jim Garrison I don't understand your comment, because the edit is passed first for revision, and if you see the edit, I only format code, nothing else , for legibilty.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you added the "0.decimal" part, but I see on review that you didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple cast from `double` to `long` *truncates* the number - basically discarding any values after the decimal point (the fractional portion).  You can use `Math.round` (round to closest whole value), `Math.floor` (round down), or `Math.ceil` (round up) for rounding it before casting.

You could also round to the closest whole number yourself by adding 0.5 before casting.

Comment: "A simple cast truncates the number" .... not every time. Try to cast to int `1.999999999999999999` and you'll be surprised that the result is `2`

Comment: More specifically, a cast discards the fractional portion of the number stored.  If you write the number you specify as a float, it does not store exactly as that value, which is why you get a different answer.  However, the cast from float (or double, etc) to int *does* discard the fractional component - every time.

Answer (score 0):

One old-school plain `C` trick was simply to add `.5` and cast :)

```
int intValue = (int)(floatValue + 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
int a = (int) Math.round(1.5);
```

The method round returns the closest long or int, as given by the methods return type.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Math.ceil`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29) first,

```
(long) Math.ceil(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `Math.ceil()` before the casting.

```
double val = 0.9;
long longValue = (long) Math.ceil ( val );
```